# Why does my code produce this output (Python)?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file into a list. However, my code doesn't produce what it's supposed to.

```
data_list = []

data_file = open('table.csv', 'r')

for line in data_file:
    data_list.append(line.strip().split(','))
    print (data_list)
```

It produces this:

[image]

I couldn't code it on here so I had to attach a photo (sorry). Why does it do this? I just want a normal list of lists.

Comment: You should use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to properly read a delimited file.

Comment: Um, what *is* it supposed to produce?

Comment: @mooiamaduck I want it to produce something like [['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], ['2016-11-08', '802.11', '816.09',....etc]] etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing inside the `for` loop. `data_list` is a list of lists, just print it after the `for` loop finishes :)

```
data_list = []

data_file = open('table.csv', 'r')

for line in data_file:
    data_list.append(line.strip().split(','))
print(data_list)
```